# Execl sum rows using MMULT ignoring blank cells

Tags: arrays, excel, matrix

I'm trying to sum all rows in a range and then get the average of non zero rows in that array in Excel. The closest I can get is :

```
{=AVERAGE(MMULT(M6:P8,SIGN(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(M6:P8)))))}
```

which works if there are no blank cells, but if there are I get #VALUE! error.
I've tried using N function within MMULT to convert blanks in the array, but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
Example:

```
    M N O P  
6   7 4 3 6  
7  
8   1 3 4 7
```

Answer should be 17.5

Comment: You can use the worksheet function `ISEMPTY` to find empty cells and replace by 0.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Wouldn't a formula like `=SUM(M6:P8)/ROWS(M6:P8)` be simpler and return the same result?

Comment: Thanks @Dominique, `ISBLANK` works when cell are truly empty, but they are actually formulas with "". I got it to work by using `IF` statement. I now just need to figure out how to ignore the zeros in the average where the entire row is empty

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij, yes! that is much simpler, thanks! I've still got the same issue with ignoring blank cells or "" in the averaging

Comment: Can you explain few results by editing post. It is hard to understand desired behavior from the formula. Workaround I suggested has no impact if you have blank cells.

Comment: Or you can modify originial formula to handle the blanks like `=AVERAGE(MMULT(IF(M6:P8<>"",M6:P8,0),SIGN(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(M6:P8)))))`.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thanks, but I still have the same issue if the entire row is blank. I've added an example in the original post

Answer (score 0):

OK, there's probably a more elegant solution, but this works:

```
{=SUM(M6:P8)/SUM(IF(MMULT(--(M6:P8<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(M6:P8)^0)),1))}
```

adapted from : https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1026823-count-non-blank-rows-array.html

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have a working solution which doesn't involve helper column, here is one approach with helper columns.

In cell Q6 put following formula:

`=(COUNT(M6:P6)>0)+0`

and copy down till Q8.

And then use formula:

`=SUM(M6:P8)/SUM(Q6:Q8)`